# No input driver specified, ignoring this device

Tags: linux, input-device, linux-device-driver, xinput

I am trying to connect my virtual gamepad device to Linux. However, opening running the console app I get the message

```
No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
This device may have been added with another device file.
```

I can read the virtual gamepad device inputs using

```
jstest /dev/input/js3
```

However, this input doesn't get applied to an actual game (Which is what I need to achieve at the end).

A little bit of debugging showed that connecting a PS4 dualshock or an xbox controller gives the same messages too.